# Best way to acceptance test SOAP Web Services?

Tags: java, cucumber, soapui, acceptance-testing, cucumber-junit

We have Java Web Services (SOAP) and some application code. We do have JUnit testing that gets done while the projects is building using JUnit and maven.

What we want is the ability to test the SOAP Web Services that can be run as an acceptance test aka testing the actual functional service. What we have at the moment is a SOAP-UI project that we run to test the web services. Most of these Web services is document style taking a single input and single output argument. To test it we using assertions in SOAP-UI to see if the output contains a certain string or count a number of tags etc.

We would like to have a project that we can run from a Integration server like Jenkins or something that is calling the actual web services like we would have using SOAP-UI and then see if the results is correct.

This needs to be automated that can either run on a schedule or on demand.

I have found the following wrt using Cucumber

[Testing a Web Service with SoapUI, JUnit, Maven and Cucumber](https://thomassundberg.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/testing-a-web-service-with-soapui-junit-maven-and-cucumber/)

But it does seem like a lot of effort for something small and don't see how I can interpret the response like I can do in SOAP-UI.

1. Is Cucumber the best option to test this in?
2. Or is there a better alternative that can be used to test with?
3. And do you know of an example on how to use it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AndyBrown - Sorry to bug but what do you mean it belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com? This is posted on stackoverflow where I have posted multiple coding questions before?

Comment: It wasn't a criticism, I actually think you'll get better answers there (the way the "vote" comment gets auto-written just sounds a bit harsh). I think this is perfect for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ as that site is for questions about "dev methodologies and processes, qa and testing" (see [what can I ask](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ), so this seems bang on topic for that site.

Comment: And even without that, this is likely to get closed down as off-topic as it's asking for "... software libraries, tutorial or other off-site resources". So I was just trying to lend you a hand.

Comment: @AndyBrown - Thanks will move it there :)